# Applying dictionary values to class objects through raw input?

Tags: python, oop, dictionary

Let's say I had a dictionary of keys and values holding information for multiple character classes, e.g. 'knight' or 'mage', and I want to apply them to a player object to determine their attributes.

```
class Player(Object):
    CHARCLASSDICT = {'knight': {'level': 4, 'health': 50, 'stamina': 50, 'mana': 50,
                                'strength': 10, 'defense': 8, 'intelligence': 8}}

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Unknown'
        self.charclass = 'Traveller'
        self.level = 1
        self.health = 1
        self.stamina = 1
        self.mana = 1
        self.strength = 1
        self.defense = 1
        self.intelligence = 1

player = Player()
```

With these values, I want the user to present me with a string of the class they wish to be, and transfer the values from the dict to the player object.

```
inp = raw_input('What class would you like to be?: ').lower()
if inp == 'knight':
    # Apply stats from self.CHARCLASSDICT['warrior'] to the player object's init function attributes.
```

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: Well, you'd write a function that takes the values out of the dictionary and assigns them to the object. I'm confused what your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

How about passing the `player_type` to the `__init__()` method?

Code -

```
class Player(object):
    CHARCLASSDICT = {'knight': {'level': 4,
                                'health': 50,
                                'stamina': 50,
                                'mana': 50,
                                'strength': 10,
                                'defense': 8,
                                'intelligence': 8}}

    def __init__(self, player_type):
        self.name = 'Unknown'
        self.charclass = 'Traveller'
        self.level = self.CHARCLASSDICT[player_type]['level']
        self.health = self.CHARCLASSDICT[player_type]['health']
        self.stamina = self.CHARCLASSDICT[player_type]['stamina']
        self.mana = self.CHARCLASSDICT[player_type]['mana']
        self.strength = self.CHARCLASSDICT[player_type]['strength']
        self.defense = self.CHARCLASSDICT[player_type]['defense']
        self.intelligence = self.CHARCLASSDICT[player_type]['intelligence']


player_type = raw_input('What type of player? : ')

player = Player(player_type)
```